# Magento Get Attribute for current product

Tags: php, magento

I am fairly new to magento development . On my product details page I have added a custom tab along additional information which shows the value of specific attribute (`video_embed_code`).

I want to display the value of this attribute in that tab. But when I try to fetch the value of attribute in my `tabs.phtml` file it gives me fatal error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in ..
```

Here is what I am using to display the attribute value :

```
$video_code=$this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('video_embed_code');
```

I have also tried

```
$video_code=$product->getAttributeText('video_embed_code');
```

But it gives same fatal error. What seems to be the problem here?

Ahmar A.

Comment: That error means that your block doesn't have access to the product, have you injected it by a controller or by the registry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this.

```
$video_code = Mage::registry('current_product')->getData('video_embed_code');
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried doing ?

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_product->getVideo_embed_code();
```

Note: In magento admin Edit the attribute(video_embed_code) & mark "Yes"
in "Visible on Product View Page on Front-end"

Comment: Call to a member function getVideo_embed_code() on a non-object in still the same